# Can "After trigger" be used on db views?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have been searching over the net if we can use an after trigger on a db view, I found it cannot be used. Please correct me if I am wrong and also let me know the reason.

Comment: You are correct. In Sql Server, you can only use instead of triggers on views.

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be done:

> 1. View its just literally intended as View for all user's.
> 2. Couldn't be inserted nor update the field like Trigger's action.

See this [view tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-views.php) for additional info.

I would suggest just use the `table` itself instead of View.